# How/Where do I check my ubuntu laptops's CPU usage?

Tags: cpu

How/Where do I check my ubuntu laptops's CPU usage?

Comment: Additionally, try out [this](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-memory-usage/) page for more information. This is very comprehensive and surely answers a lot of queries, although I personally feel using [system monitor](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-system-monitor/) is the best solution.

Answer (score 193):

### HTOP

is a lightweight text-mode process viewer packed with handy features such as killing processes without entering their PID, displaying full command lines, etc with a colour display

**How to install**

open your Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> ) and Type

```
sudo apt-get install htop
```

**To run:** type `htop` This will show what you are asking. .

[image]

Comment: @stephen-myall Thanks for edit . its look nice now .

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer when an earlier answer provided a faster builtin solution?  This answers questions that weren't even asked.

Comment: @deanresin I completely agree with you. But if you know how to use htop then you will know how to monitor each CPU core performance. Thank you.

Comment: If `F10` does not quit htop but shows some menu, as prompted at bottom, press `q` or `ctrl - c` to exit.

Answer (score 89):

In your dash i.e. pressing `super` key search for [system monitor](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-system-monitor/) application.

[image]

If you are comfortable with command line there are tools like `top` and `htop` where cpu usage can be viewed as well.

Comment: gnome-system-monitor is not installed by default on Ubuntu 18.04 anymore for some reason, you need `sudo apt install gnome-system-monitor` first: http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.manifest

Answer (score 35):

As said in previous answer you can use system monitor which is the best tool. If you want more information you can try some commands on terminal

`top` - its a command to see all the processes and their CPU usage. Just read the screen carefully and you would find lot of other useful information there.
you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to close it.

Or you can also try
`cat /proc/cpuinfo` - for other information about cpu

Comment: You can also quit top by simply pressing the `q` key

Comment: "As said in previous answer you can use system monitor which is the best tool" - best out of which other tools? Have you tried `KSysGuard`, for example?