# How to ensure Ubuntu is using all my cores

Tags: amd-processor

I have a 6 core processor and have noticed some performance issues.  I recognize coming from Windows things won't be the same.  But I've heard that it's not incredibly uncommon for linux to not utilize all cores available.  Is there a command or series of commands to be sure linux recognizes my processor runs all 6 cores?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably test your CPUs by running a CPU-intensive process and watching the System Monitor or some equivalent. If you don't find the system monitor or want an alternative, try [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114997/how-where-do-i-check-my-ubuntu-laptopss-cpu-usage) for more details.