# Ubuntu 16.04 fresh install, extremely slow

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, performance

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 (ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso) dual boot alongside Windows 10. Installation went smoothly until a restart. I boots up very quickly, but after I log in everything becomes unusable. Even simple menu button click takes like 5 seconds to process. Everything is extremely laggy, meanwhile on Windows everything runs perfectly.

I need to use Ubuntu for certain software, could anyone point me to the solution or a at least give a hint?

P.S. I know what does it look when software renderer is used instead of GPU drivers. My case is much worse. It is not only about UI performance, it is about performance in general.

My PC specs: ASRock motherboard with Intel H170 chipset, Core i7 6700, 16GB DDR4, 480GB SSD, Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080

Comment: Can you see in the system monitor if some process is using too much resources?
http://askubuntu.com/questions/114997/how-where-do-i-check-my-ubuntu-laptopss-cpu-usage/115044

Comment: Can you please check if this issue  http://askubuntu.com/questions/816804/chrome-high-gpu-usage-and-low-fps-while-scrolling-the-page reproducing on your build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by installing proprietary Nvidia graphics driver.

I noticed that Xorg process has been using 99.9 of CPU